# Can this famous theorem extended to the weighted undirected graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

There is well-known bound on the largest eigenvalue of graphs that says $$\sqrt{d_{max}}\leq \lambda_{max}$$. Is it also true for weighted graphs? (Where as usual, the degree of a vertex in a weighted graph is defined as sum of the weights of its incident edges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a star on$1+k$ vertices with edge weights $w_1,\ldots,w_k$, then its spectral radius is $(w_1^2+\cdots+w_k^2)^{1/2}$. Since the spectral radius of a subgraph is a lower bound on the spectral radius of the graph, this is a lower bound on $\lambda_\max$. So your extension works if we use the "appropriate" version of degree.

If $w_i<1$ for all $i$, then your proposed extension fails for weighted stars.